# Soundrecorder get wavein volume

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I use soundrecorder in batch files to auto-record audio at my radio station.

Is there any easy way to get the waveout or wavein volume? It would be useful in setting up
alarms that sense silence at some of our remote transmitters.